# Formatting dataset for ML regression model

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a kaggle dataset for which there are column names with subcolumns. How do I format this?

I did import it using pandas but below is the output when I try :

```
data = pd.read_csv('Residential-Building-Data-Set.csv',encoding= 'unicode_escape')

data.head()
print(data.columns)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Index(['ï»¿PROJECT DATES (PERSIAN CALENDAR)', 'Unnamed: 1', 'Unnamed: 2',
       'Unnamed: 3', 'PROJECT PHYSICAL AND FINANCIAL VARIABLES', 'Unnamed: 5',
       'Unnamed: 6', 'Unnamed: 7', 'Unnamed: 8', 'Unnamed: 9',
       ...
       'Unnamed: 99', 'Unnamed: 100', 'Unnamed: 101', 'Unnamed: 102',
       'Unnamed: 103', 'Unnamed: 104', 'Unnamed: 105', 'Unnamed: 106',
       'OUTPUTS', 'Unnamed: 108'],
      dtype='object', length=109)
```

Comment: you want to format the columns or the subcolumns ?  explain clearly please.

Comment: also please provide example data:  the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example